# what does kernel do behind the scene

Tags: linux

I would like to know the exact sequence of steps that the OS does, when I type simple command like "ls -l" in any directory. What actually happens behind the scene ?

I would like to know what kernel does behind the scene while executing even a simple command like this.

Comment: http://systhread.net/texts/200606kern_def.php

Comment: The shell process is `fork`ed and then replaced by the new child process using a function of the `exec` family. `exec` loads the executable into memory, etc. Very vague question, try to be more specific

Answer (score 2):

You could look at an [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)

`strace ls -l`

Comment: That will show all the system calls, but not "what the kernel does behind the scenes"